# ASP.NET MVC 3 Facebook integration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can i integrate facebook API into my asp.net mvc3 project? I mean login by Facebook. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use Facebook Library package References SDK. It can be installed from your Visual Studio.

Here is   
[Code Source](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5249810/habrapost01/FBIntegrationSample.zip)